# Applying a function only to the highlighted cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of data some of them are highlighted some are not. Is there a way to apply a function (any function) only to those highlighted cells in excel? I made a little search on Internet, and I found out there are some ways to use sumif function and Vba codes but they are only applicable to a certain function. Thanks.

I have a VBA function and I would like to use it only with highlighted cells. The code available below. In the example below, I would like to concatenate  highlighted cells only.

[image]

```
Function Concatenatecells(ConcatArea As Range) As String
'updateby Extendoffice 20151103
  For Each n In ConcatArea: nn = IIf(n = "", nn & "", nn & n & ","): Next
  Concatenatecells = Left(nn, Len(nn) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the *InteriorColor* of each cell:

```
Function Concatenatecells(ConcatArea As Range) As String
    Dim n As Range, nn As String
    nn = ""
    For Each n In ConcatArea
        If n.Interior.Color <> 16777215 Then
            nn = IIf(n = "", nn & "", nn & n & ",")
        End If
    Next n

    If nn <> "" Then
        Concatenatecells = Left(nn, Len(nn) - 1)
    Else
        Concatenatecells = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I assume there is not a specific function for this task in excel.

Comment: @Max  I think you are correct.......look at ***SpecialCells*** to see if anything applies.